# Distance measurement using Ultrasonic and ATMEGA32

Tags: embedded, avr, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm working on a Distance measurement program using an AVR microcontroller. I use a 16x2 LCD and an ultrasonic sensor along with ATMEGA32A. I wrote a code to display the distance from the Ultrasonic HC-SR04 on the LCD screen, but it gives me false readings, it increases the distance when the object is very near and vice versa. I just want an accurate reading.

[Ultrasonic datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf)
[ATMEGA32A Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmega32A-DataSheet-Complete-DS40002072A.pdf)
[image]

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <MrLcd/MrLCDmega32.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define  Trigger_pin    PD0 /* Trigger pin */


static volatile int pulse = 0;
static volatile int i = 0;

int main(void)
{
    
    Initialise();
    DDRD = 0b11111011;
    _delay_ms(50);

    GICR |= 1<<INT0;
    MCUCR |= 1<<ISC00;
    
    int16_t count_a = 0;
    char show_a[16];

    sei();
    
    while(1)
    {
        PORTD |= (1<<Trigger_pin);
        _delay_us(10);

        PORTD &= ~(1<<Trigger_pin);
        count_a = pulse/58;

        Send_A_String("Distance Sensor");
        GoToMrLCDLocation(1,2);
        Send_A_String("Distance=");
        itoa(count_a,show_a,10);
        Send_A_String(show_a);
        Send_A_String(" ");
        GoToMrLCDLocation(13,2);
        Send_A_String("cm");
        GoToMrLCDLocation(1,1);
    }
}

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
        TCCR1B = 0;
        pulse = TCNT1;
        TCNT1 = 0;
        i = 0;
    }

    if(i==0)
    {
        TCCR1B |= 1<<CS10;
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

I tried to change the trigger pin definition and define it in the code itself but still no progress.

Update: I changed a bit more in the code but I'm getting hex values when the distance is more than 9, for example, 10 is being displayed as 1e.

This is for initialise function

```c
void Initialise(void)
{        
    DataDir_MrLCDsControl|=1<<LightSwitch|1<<ReadWrite|1<<BipolarMood;  //these information will go towards the LCD
        
    _delay_ms(15);                              // Wait for the LCD to start
    
    Send_A_Command(0x01);   // to clear the screen
    _delay_ms(2);
    Send_A_Command(0x38);   // TO tell LCD about 8 data lines
    _delay_us(50);
    Send_A_Command(0b00001110); //Some cursor command
    _delay_us(50);
}
```

Comment: You will probably have to give us some information on the sensor your are using (data sheet link) and how you have connected it perhaps.  Also some concrete data, for example the reported value at 20, 30 and 40 cm = _"it increases the distance when the object is very near and vice versa._" is just a bit too vague.  Some comments in the code explaining how you _think_ it is working would he helpful (to you as much as us I suspect).  What is the clock rate of TMR1.  What does `Initialise()` do, and why is it done twice?

Comment: done please check

Comment: The display in hex is hard to understand if you are using `itoa` with base-10.  That is clearly a different issue, and without the modified code cannot be addressed in any case.

Comment: `pulse / 58` looks wrong too.  At 1MHz, the number of pulses per cm would ne ~14.57, so  you would have `distance = pulse * 100 / 1457 ;`

Comment: ... ok, it seems that `Initialise()` is entirely related to display initialisation.  I would suggest `DisplayInitialise()` or something similar.  Otherwise it suggest something more general.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending pulses at a very rapid rate (determined solely by the display update time), and they are asynchronous to the time/counter reset.  You have no idea which pulse triggered the interrupt and it did not start at the same time as the timer.

I would suggest that you reset the counter at the start of the pulse, and capture the counter value on interrupt.  When the time has exceeded the maximum range, send a new pulse:

First define some constants:

```c
#define PULSES_PER_CMx100 (F_CPU * 100 / 68600)
#define MAX_RANGE_CM 300
#define MAX_RANGE_COUNT ((MAX_RANGE_CM * PULSES_PER_CMx100) / 100)
```

Then your measure/display loop might look like:

```c
    pulse = 1 ; // dummy start
    GICR &= ~(1<<INT0) ;  // Disable INT0

    for(;;)
    {
        // Ready for new measurement?...
        if( pulse != 0 )
        {
            // Send pulse and reset timer
            PORTD |= (1<<Trigger_pin) ;
            pulse = 0 ;
            TCNT1 = 0 ;
            _delay_us(10);
            PORTD &= ~(1<<Trigger_pin) ;

            // Wait for echo pulse interrupt...
            GIFR |= 1<<INTF0;  // Clear INT0 pending flag
            GICR |= 1<<INT0 ;  // Enable INT0
        }
        else  // When measurement available...
        {
            int distance_cm = pulse * 100 / PULSES_PER_CMx100 ;

            // display distance
            ...
        }

        // If out of range, timeout, send a new pulse
        if( TCNT1 > MAX_RANGE_COUNT )
        {
            // Force a new pulse to be triggered
            pulse = 1 ;
        }
    }
```

And the ISR:

```c
ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    pulse = TCNT1;       // Capture time on interrupt
    GICR &= ~(1<<INT0) ; // Disable further interrupts
}
```

Now bear in mind that that method will take measurements as fast as possible and since you are displaying them for human reading, that is rather unnecessary.  You might simply put a delay in the loop - making the pulse timeout unnecessary, or better you could take the mean of multiple measurements to get a more robust measurement, or use a moving average window, with outlier rejection.

Comment: from where you got EIFR? It's undefined

Comment: @AnonymousStress :  Sorry - different AVR part - assumed it was common.  Let me think about that.

Comment: @AnonymousStress :  Corrected to GIFR for ATMega32A.  Note that I do not have the means to test this code, you should treat it as illustrative of the technique rather than definitive.  The comment should have been enough for you to figure that out.